# Is there any difference between the "grammatical-number" and "pluralization" tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is there any difference between [grammatical-number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-number) and [pluralization](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pluralization), or should the tags be merged?

Does using both the tags in the same question means anything?

Comment: I can't find the grammar-number tag, or questions with it... Is it me?

Comment: It was me; I didn't write the tag correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  I already made plural and singular synonyms for grammatical number. I will do the same with pluralization.

Comment: And it is done! Hope no one disagreed. ;-)